# Python how to type hint a 2D list?

Tags: python

How do I type check for a 2d list?
I know type checking a 1d list in a functions parameter would be:

```
apples = list(["granny smith","fiji"])
foo(apples)
def foo(fruits:list):
    print("Typed check passed")
```

But how do it for a 2d list?

```
board=list([list([1,2]),list([3,4])])
bar(board)
def bar(board:list:list): # My Guess Attempt
    print("Type check passed")
```

Comment: Why don't you apply your first test to both `board` and `board[0]`?

Comment: you don't need to do this: `apples = list(["granny smith","fiji"])` you can just do `apples = ["granny smith","fiji"]` ... the list-literal syntax (square brackets) already creates a list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [generic concrete collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Dict):

```py
# for python >= 3.9
def bar(list[list[int]]):
    ...

# for older versions:
from typing import List

def bar(List[List[int]]):
    ...
```

Assuming, the type of the list elements should be `int` - otherwise just use the corresponding type or skip the second set of brackets.

Comment: FYI [since Python 3.9](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/) you don't need `typing.List` and can just use `list` e.g. `list[list[int]]`

Answer (score 0):

You are using type hinting, not type checking

You can use this code

```
from typing import List
def bar(board: List[List[int]]):
    # your code
    print("Type check passed")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
board=list([list([1,2]),list([3,4])])
bar(board)
def bar(board:list[list]):
    print("Type check passed")
```